# Bootstrap Tabs in IE7

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs, internet-explorer-7, jquery-ui-tabs

I am creating a webpage similar to wikipedia. And I am using Twitter Bootstrap.

For designing a tab I am using bootstrap as in the url 
[Bootstrap Tabs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs)

In IE7 my tabs are looking like below

[image: IE7 Tabs]

In Chrome it is looking great

[image: Chrome Tabs]

Please help

Code

[image]

Comment: They work on the TBS site, right? You have to show your code. :)

Comment: Yes they work on TBS site. I know I am doing some mistake here :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code as posted in the screenshot is giving me the following output..

[image]

You can check if the issue remains after clearing browser cache.

I was using only

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css" />
```

and no other *css* or *js* file..

Comment: is this something to do with doctype?. My server is Lotus Domino 6.5. My doctype is <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

Comment: not sure that whether it's a doctype issue or not..you can use `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">` and check..i was using _XAMPP_..

Comment: Fixed it. The issue is with doctype. It worked after changing the doctype to <!DOCTYPE html>